# Different Airflow branching based on environment variable?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Is it possible to change branches based on environment variable set in Airflow.
For example:
`Variable.get(‘Enviroment’)` returns “dev”, “test”, or “prod”
Let’s say I have at task, Task_B, that I don’t want to run in “dev”.

```
Start_dag_task = DummyOperator(task_id=”Start_dag_task”, ...)
Task_A = PythonOperator(task_id=”Task_A”,…)
Task_B = PythonOperator(task_id=”Task_B”,…) (Do not run in dev environment)
Task_C= PythonOperator(task_id=”Task_C”,…)
End_dag_task = DummyOperator(task_id=”End_dag_task”, …)

env = Variable.get(“Environment”)
Start_dag_task >> Task_A >> End_dag_task
if  env != “dev”:
   Start_dag_task >> Task_B >> End_dag_task
Start_dag_task >> Task_C >> End_dag_task
```

Is this possible, to run this same code in all three environments and have Task_B not run in Dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding a `ShortCircuitOperator` before task B to check if the variable `env` value is `dev` or not, if it's `dev`, the task B will be skipped. But you need to set `ignore_downstream_trigger_rules` to `False` in order to execute the End_dag_task and the others downstream tasks, and set End_dag_task `trigger_rule` to `NONE_FAILED` to execute when the task B state is success or skipped:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import ShortCircuitOperator, PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule


with DAG(
    "dag_id",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
) as dag:

    Start_dag_task = EmptyOperator(task_id="Start_dag_task")
    Task_A = PythonOperator(task_id="Task_A", python_callable=lambda: print("Task A"))
    Task_B = PythonOperator(task_id="Task_B", python_callable=lambda: print("B"))
    Task_C = PythonOperator(task_id="Task_C", python_callable=lambda: print("C"))
    End_dag_task = EmptyOperator(task_id="End_dag_task", trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED)

    shortCircuitTaskB = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id="short_circuit_for_task_B",
        python_callable=lambda: Variable.get("env", "default_env") != "dev",
        ignore_downstream_trigger_rules=False,
    )

    Start_dag_task >> Task_A >> End_dag_task
    Start_dag_task >> shortCircuitTaskB >> Task_B >> End_dag_task
    Start_dag_task >> Task_C >> End_dag_task
```

Comment: Thanks, @HusseinAwala.   I will try this next week.  I appreciate the guidance. +1